# I have a url in string.xml file inside <a href tag which has dynamic values. how to open that url in webview?

Tags: android, string.xml

`<string name="xyz">This is my string with url <a href="example://xyz.com:api/deviceconfig/dynamicValue()/something?some_token=dynamic_vlaue&amp; locale=en"></a></string>`

dynamic values will change everytime. How to make proper url and open it in webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) of an Activity Context to Get String. And use that String in WebView's [loadUrl()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String)) method.

Example

```
String url = getString(R.id.url_in_string);
yourWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Yes. That is to load url in webview. However, my string has some dymanic values which I need to get everytime. And I can not get dynamic values in string.xml file.

Comment: do you mean you want to set some String values in string.xml at runtime? Is it?

Comment: yes. The url in string.xml froms with some dynamic values which are device dependent so everytime I run my app those values would be different.

Comment: Then Why are you putting it in string.xml? Simply you can use one public class with static variable.

Comment: Glad to help you! Thanks for marking! See if You can upvote! :)